# check if a page has been redirected and then add a class to a certain div

Tags: 7, javascript, redirection

Im using the redirect module to redirect /page/scheduling to  /page.

I need to check if the user arrived to a certain page by this redirect.

by checking this i will then add a class to a certain div.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting to /page you redirect to /page?hello=world then you can check in JS for that URL query param and fire your magic.